# Set password for RStudio Server with AWS EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio, rstudio-server

I managed to follow all the steps to create EC2 instance and install R Server on it.

When I go to RStudio Server page to connect *(which looks something like "ec2-[Public IP]-.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8787")*, I am asked a username and a password.

I figured out to set a username ("user1") this way:

```
$ sudo useradd user1
```

But then when I try this command to write the password:

```
echo user1:password | chpasswd
```

I receive this message:
***chpasswd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.***

I looked at different solutions suggested here:

https://superuser.com/questions/296373/cannot-lock-etc-passwd-try-again-later

but I do not see a resolution to my problem.

I did not find either any *passwd.lock, shadow.lock, group.lock, gshadow.lock* files to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

type in 'sudo passwd *your_username*' and you will be prompted to enter a new password

Comment: Thank you !! For newbies like me, do not expect the characters of the password to show up when you type the letters, just press enter and retype again the password.